# Can we use 2 domains (for ex mywebsite1.com and mywebsite2.com) and use the same S3 website for both domains in AWS? How?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, cname

I have to use two domain names mywebsite1.com and mywebsite2.com to host the same S3 website. I own both the domains and I have programmed the mywebsite2.com to redirect the  traffic to mywebsite1.com but that changes the  URL to mywebsite1.com which I do not want. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two domains for pointing to the same S3 website by leveraging following services of AWS - `S3` , `Cloudfront` and `Certificate manager`.

You can refer to the following [article](https://medium.com/@taoyil/serve-static-website-through-multiple-domains-on-aws-f764ee174012) which explains the complete steps for achieving it.

Comment: What if my both websites i have bought from GoDaddy?